# Windows took control over "docs" folder

Tags: windows-7

I've always had a folder named "docs" on my slave partition (D:). A few weeks ago, I believe the Windows system decided to take over it... what happened:

- It renamed the folder to "Documents" - weirdly, for some time I was able to access it by using /docs/ on command-line and some software even though it displayed 'Documents' on the shell. Now it is impossible to access /docs/ anymore... I have to go for /Documents/ everytime.
- It made it impossible to rename the folder, even when I use those popular "Take ownership" scripts. I have several folders and files inside this one, which can move/rename/delete on will daily.

Using Windows 7 Ultimate.

What on earth happened here? I never saw this behavior before. Could it be a virus of some sort?

ps: I did no modifications or updates to the SO for months before that...

Comment: Try recreating your "docs" folder and copying/moving everything in "Documents" to it.

Comment: there is very little likelihood that malware is involved.